# Shortcut to add faces following the loop when re-topology

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

let's say I'm in the situation shown in the image here under:
I want to quick add edges/faces following the loop.
The method I'm using is "select 4 vertex" and add face with F. But this is quite long and I saw many 3d artists doing it very quickly (without the need of selecting vertexes all the time).

I'm also using F2 addon, but I don't think it can help in this context.

[image: l]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, select only the yellow edge and press <kbd>F</kbd> and it will fill the whole face, and if you press <kbd>F</kbd> again it will go on with the following ones. It looks like you doesn't even need the F2 addon:

[image]

Or in *Edge* or *Vertex Select* mode, select the whole edge around and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill* and it will fill the whole with a row of faces.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, it works perfectly!

Comment: you're welcome. I don't know why your question is greyed though, have deleted it?

Comment: no, I see it as normal